# ProgrammingError when switching from Sqlite3 to Postgresql in django admin console

Tags: python, django, postgresql

In django, I have attempted to switch from using an sqlite3 database to postgresql. `settings.py` has been switched to connect to postgres. Both `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` run without errors. `makemigrations` says that it creates the models for the database, however when running `migrate`, it says there is no changes to be made.

The django server will run, however when clicking on a specfic table in the database in the `/admin` webpage, it throws the error:

```
ProgrammingError at /admin/app/tablename/
relation "app_tablename" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "app_tablename"
```

With the same code (other than `settings.py` database connection) this worked when using sqlite3.

Comment: Does `app_tablename` exist in the database?

Comment: If you have clean migration files and are changing to a brand new database, there should be no problem at all. Could you try connecting to a newly created database and then running the `python manage.py migrate` command there !

Comment: I opened psql on command line and ran `SELECT * FROM app_tablename` and got `relation "app_tablename" does not exist` . It's been defined in `models.py`, but doesn't seem to be creating the tables in postgres.

Comment: @ZenonasSakkas if your problem was solved, please mark the question as "closed"

Comment: Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Happened same thing to me. i deleted the table from database then created the migration again using `python manage.py makemigrations` . Then i ran that particular migration again using `python manage.py migrate myapp 00123` assuming that appname is myapp and migration name is 00123.py

Comment: I can't test this since I created a new database which solved the problem, but thank you

Answer (score 0):

What I did was create a new database and switched to it through the `settings.py` file. After that, migrations should happen with no problems